# Express Server not Serving Static Files from Index.html

Tags: node.js, express, path, mean-stack

This question has been asked multiple times I know, but I have searched and tried everything, and it still doesn't work. I'm new to Node. My file directory is set up like this:

```
io
-node_modules/
-app/
     --css
     --js
-index.html
-server.js
```

**Server.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
//app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/app/css'));
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname+'/app/css'));
var server=require('http').createServer(app);
var io=require('socket.io').listen(server);
users=[];
connections=[];



//set up server
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3001);
console.log('Server running...');

//create a route
app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname+'/app/index.html');
});
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame
        Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

        <title>IO Chat</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="Lloyd">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">

    <link href="css/main.css" rel="sylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="sylesheet">
    <!--link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"-->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.5.1/socket.io.js"></script>
    </head>
```

So what I need to know is why index.html doesn't seem to able to reference my css files. I've tried multiple possible combinations in `app.use()` and it just doesn't want to work, even though at times I can get to the file directly from the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the server:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/app/css'));
```

in the client:

```
<link href="/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Nope, nothing. Nada :( Mind you, I can access the CSS file itself, the index file is just not behaving properly. So I'm thinking it's how I've set my `app.get()`

Comment: You can always access files with the absolute path, you don't need the static serving at all. Btw, what do mean by "not behaving properly", what is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you showed us the proper directory structure? You send `__dirname + "/app/index.html"` - is it ok? From your info I rather see it should be `__dirname + "/index.html"`

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I recently took out the index.html file and put it into the root. Nothing. I've tried everything I can. By not behaving properly I mean that it's not referencing the css files.

Comment: You made a typo - should be `rel="stylesheet"` - you typed "sylesheet" instead ;-)

Comment: OH MY GOD!!! How the heck did I miss that? This thing has been bugging me all day, and one letter spoiled it all. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using the `app.use` wrong

Try it like this :

```
app.use('css', express.static(__dirname+'/app/css'));
```

this routes calls to `css/...` to the static dir named.

Comment: I think so too. But it's still not working. Right now it's `app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname+'/app/css'));` and even though I can access the css file by going to localhost:3001/css/main.css, index.html just won't reference it. It's kinda puzzling.